# Knowing when prefetch is happening in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, prefetch, prerender

Is there any way to see when prefetching is happening in Firefox? In Chrome there is an internal task manager which shows when websites is being pre-rendered in background is there anything similar for Firefox pre-fetching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to confirm that a resource has been prefetched by Firefox is to load the page that triggers the prefetching and then take a look at the contents of the browser cache by browsing to `about:cache` and clicking on `List Cache Entries`.

If you clear your cache just before you do that, it will be pretty obvious whether or not these resources were prefetched successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't prefetch entire sites; it only prefetches particular resources that are declared as needing prefetching or are parsed as part of a page.

There is no way to see when the prefetching is happening, though one could be added.  What's the use case?

Comment: I would like to see it just to test/verify that prefetching is working as I expect. I know there is a way to tell it from server logs because firefox sends special header when prefetching, but its quite a big effort when I only want see if this is working at all.

Comment: Firefox doesn't send any special headers when speculatively loading subresources.  If you just want to see whether `<link rel=prefetch>` is being prefetched, then anything that shows network traffic (Firebug, the built-in web console, any of a variety of HTTP traffic analysis extensions available for Firefox) will tell you that.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Link_prefetching_FAQ
they write that "X-moz: prefetch" header is sent with prefetch request.

Do you have/know any working prefetch example for me to test and see its traffic in firebug net panel or other HTTP traffic analysis tool? I have created several test pages and I fail to see any traffic from <link rel=prefetch>